# Keycloak Invalid Redirect Uri, Page not found error

Tags: angular, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-js

I am trying to integrating keycloak with angular but I am facing issue **invalid_redirect_uri/Page_not_found error.**

[image: error login]

[image: Here is the Keycload configuration:]

[image: Angular setting]

[image: console]

Spent hours on googling but failed.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the full authorization url which the angular app constructs? it's shortened in your first image.

Comment: here: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/web-portal/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=web-angular&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2F&state=c0471008-4019-46f8-9fcc-872b076d4b42&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=8aeabf9e-a9f5-482e-8233-e1a6e0c975ad

Comment: Image added.. Now you can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it too long for a comment I will post here.
I am assuming you have not changed the default keycloak port, there is only one possible issue I see
By default keycloak quarkus has removed the /auth from it api's and you need to explicitly set if you require this property.

```
http-relative-path=/auth
```

This can be set in the keycloak.conf file in /conf directory.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to get the right configuration settings is in the upper right corner on the client detail page.

There is a dropdown with the option

> Download adapter config

This should present the config to you, as Keycloak expects it to be.

Comment: Yes I see that. But the error remain same

Comment: @HamidShah so, you have configured the same values as shown in the adapter config? especially the /auth part because in the newer versions this is removed by default.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just had to remove `auth` from url and it started working.